# Maximal subgroups of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Question : What are the maximal subgroups of $A_n$?

I know that $A_n$ is simple group that means there no non-trivial subgroup which is normal in $A_n$.

Comment: A_4 has a nontrivial normal subgroup

Answer (score 1):

There is no complete classification. They split up into three classes, the intransitive maximals, the imprimitive maximals, and the primitive maximals.

The first two are relatively easily described. The intransitives have the structure $(A_k \times A_{n-k}).2$ for $1 \le k < n$. The imprimitives are the intersections of $S_k \wr S_{n/k}$ with $A_n$ for divisors $k$ of $n$ with $1 < k < n$.

The primitive maximals can be further subdivided into classes using the O'Nan-Scott Theorem. But there is unlikely ever to be a complete description of almost simple primitive maximal subgroups of $A_n$, since that would itself require a detailed knowledge of all maximal subgroups of all simple groups, and so the problems seems to be recursive.

See [this reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387902237).

Comment: primitive maximal means let $H \le G$ which is primitive maximal then group action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ is primitive? is it the definition of primitive maximals?

Comment: A primitive maximal is a maximal subgroup of $A_n$ that is primitive in its natural action on $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. It has nothing to do with the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$. (Any subgroup of $H$ of any group $G$ is maximal if and only if the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ is primitive.)